# Is there anyway to link to your homepage without the index (somesite.com vs somesite.com/index)?

Tags: html

I uploaded a site, and I'm trying to get the links to redirect to somesite.com instead of somesite.com/index. I've tried putting blank spaces, but it seems to stay on the current page. Is there anyway to accomplish this without putting the full URL?

Comment: Direct to root using `/` like so: `<a href="/">Home</a>`, or full path `<a href="http://example.com">Home</a>`

Comment: <a href = "/"> seems to do the trick... if you put that in the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `/` to access the root, like so:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```